# EDIT: Possible different issue. CPU spiking in Xorg/Gnome vs. Wayland, NOT specifically with Firefox (Ubuntu 20.04) (Firefox 88.0.1 (64-bit))

Tags: gnome, xorg, firefox, wayland

After experiencing some issues in Wayland (not tracking my Rescuetime app, a few other programs not working) I switched back to Xorg/Gnome.

Since doing this, I've noticed that when using Firefox, particularly when opening a new tab, I'll get a CPU spike that I didn't experience in Wayland.

Going by the System Monitor, it's still 'firefox' and 'Web Content' that are eating the CPU, but the fact that this is newer behaviour and occurred after switching back to Xorg/Gnome, makes me think there's a link there.

My google-fu couldn't find anything specific, so I thought I'd ask here!

If it's a Xorg/Gnome issue, then maybe I'll try something like Xfce or some other lighter weight window manager that still plays well with Rescuetime and the other apps I'm using.

EDIT: I have seen this behaviour even when Firefox is closed. I thought it was caused perhaps by Zoom, but it does the same even outside of that program as well.

EDIT: I haven't had the problem occur unless the webcam is activated at some point, at least so far. This problem may not be connected to Xorg, Firefox, or Zoom. Will report back if I discover anything new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a log or any other explanation about what's going on.

It's possible that my particular mix of OS, windowing system, programs, and hardware didn't manifest for too many other people!

I did upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04, and the problem has *mostly* stopped. The CPU will sometimes spike again during browser-based chats such as Google Meet.

If you've experienced a similar issue and have found your way here, consider upgrading to the most recent version of Ubuntu!